# Intellij wants my destructured javascript object formatted to one line

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, formatting

I have not been able to get IntelliJ to format destructured objects in the same way as normal ones.  The following is an example of what the formatter produces given the same object 3 ways.

```
async function main({
                      login_user = process.env.MYSQL_USER, login_password = process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD, login_host = 'localhost', login_port = 3306, user = '', password = '', ncrypted = false, host = '127.0.0.1', host_all = false, state = 'present', priv: privString = '', append_privs = false, update_password = 'always', name = '',
                    }) {
  const o = {
    login_user,
    login_password,
    login_host,
    login_port,
    user,
    password,
    ncrypted,
    host,
    host_all,
    state,
    priv,
    append_privs,
    update_password,
    name,
  };
  const {
    login_user = process.env.MYSQL_USER, login_password = process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD, login_host = 'localhost', login_port = 3306, user = '', password = '', ncrypted = false, host = '127.0.0.1', host_all = false, state = 'present', priv: privString = '', append_privs = false, update_password = 'always', name = '',
  } = o;
}
```

My settings are as follows (I've also tried the Standard Javascript, Google Javascript and Drupal javascript presets.  All with the same results).

[image: My Objects: Wrap Always setting looks OK]

I know the formatter works on regular objects (the middle declaration), but there is no specific heading for 'destructured objects'.  Does this mean the IntelliJ formatter doesn't currently support formatting destructured objects?

Using PHPStorm 2019.3.1

Comment: The object in the argument is totally missformed. Instead of `=` you should use `:`.

Comment: @Teemu woops, fixed

Comment: Not supported yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31028